# How can I filter and map over an array at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am trying to arrange data to feed into Recharts. Not sure exactly how to rearrange the data properly. Recharts provides this structure for line charts which I have tested:

```
data = [
    {
      name: '2017-01-01', gr: 4000, hv: 2400
    },
    {
      name: '2017-01-02', gr: 3000, hv: 1398
    },
    {
      name: '2017-01-03', gr: 2000, hv: 9800
    }
  ];
```

I have a json file that I need to rearrange into a similar format:

```
[
    {
      "Month/Year": "2019-09",
      "group": "blue",
      "flights": "668620"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "blue",
        "flights": "662520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-09",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "662520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "678520"
    }
]
```

I am trying to process the data by mapping over it:

```
processData = (data) => {
    return data.map(e => ({
      name: e['Month/Year'],
      gr: e[THIS WOULD BE green IN group],
      hv: e[THIS WOULD BE blue IN group]
    }));
  };
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
data = [
    {
      name: '2019-09', gr: 662520, hv: 668620
    },
    {
      name: '2019-10', gr: 678520, hv: 662520
    }
  ];
```

I believe I have to filter somehow to pivot the data into the appropriate format. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you have to filter (at least it doesn't seem so), you just seem to need to map it into different labels, from month to name, group to gr and flights to hv. But I could be wrong

Comment: What are you wanting to filter?

Comment: My assumption was that I could use filter in some way to extract all the blues and greens separately and then feed them into the respective "gr" and "hv" categories, wasn't sure if there was a way to do this. I'm coming from the data world and am relatively new to javascript so I may be off here.

Comment: Something like [Lodash's `_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you are trying to group data by month and adding up flight counts by blue and green group?

Comment: Please provide the expected format you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a hash table and get the values from it.

```js
var data = [{ "Month/Year": "2019-09", group: "blue", flights: "668620" }, { "Month/Year": "2019-10", group: "blue", flights: "662520" }, { "Month/Year": "2019-09", group: "green", flights: "662520" }, { "Month/Year": "2019-10", group: "green", flights: "678520" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var name = o["Month/Year"];
        r[name] = r[name] || { name };
        r[name][{ green: 'gr', blue: 'hv'}[o.group]] = o.flights;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to determine the `JSON['group']`, to obtain the correct setting the `JSON['flights']` value.

Pair this with a look-up on the current reduced results, and you can update values or add new items as they arrive.

```js
var rawData = [
  { "Month/Year": "2019-09", "group": "blue",  "flights": "668620" },
  { "Month/Year": "2019-10", "group": "blue",  "flights": "662520" },
  { "Month/Year": "2019-09", "group": "green", "flights": "662520" },
  { "Month/Year": "2019-10", "group": "green", "flights": "678520" }
];

console.log(processData(rawData));

function processData(data) {
  return data.reduce((result, item, index) => {
    let found = result.find(d => d.name === item['Month/Year']);
    if (found) {
      Object.assign(found, {
        gr : item['group'] === 'green' ? item['flights'] : found.gr,
        hv : item['group'] === 'blue' ? item['flights'] : found.hv
      });
    } else {
      result.push({
        name : item['Month/Year'],
        gr   : item['group'] === 'green' ? item['flights'] : null,
        hv   : item['group'] === 'blue'  ? item['flights'] : null,
      });
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

### Dynamic Example

```js
var rawData = [
  { "Month/Year": "2019-09", "group": "blue",  "flights": "668620" },
  { "Month/Year": "2019-10", "group": "blue",  "flights": "662520" },
  { "Month/Year": "2019-09", "group": "green", "flights": "662520" },
  { "Month/Year": "2019-10", "group": "green", "flights": "678520" }
];

console.log(processData(rawData, 'Month/Year', {
  gr : (item) => item['group'] === 'green' ? item['flights'] : null,
  hv : (item) => item['group'] === 'blue' ? item['flights'] : null
}));

function processData(data, key, mappers) {
  return data.reduce((result, item, index) => {
    let found = result.find(d => d.name === item[key]);
    if (found) {
      Object.keys(mappers).forEach(key => found[key] = mappers[key](item) || found[key]);
    } else {
      result.push(Object.keys(mappers).reduce((obj, key) => {
        return Object.assign(obj, { [key] : mappers[key](item) })
      }, { name : item[key] }));
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather simple way to do it. It is very similar to Mr. Polywhirl's answer after I corrected it.

```js
var newData = [];
var data = [{
    "Month/Year": "2019-09",
    "group": "blue",
    "flights": "668620"
  },
  {
    "Month/Year": "2019-10",
    "group": "blue",
    "flights": "662520"
  },
  {
    "Month/Year": "2019-09",
    "group": "green",
    "flights": "662520"
  },
  {
    "Month/Year": "2019-10",
    "group": "green",
    "flights": "678520"
  }
];

data.forEach((item, index) => {
    let temp = {};
    let exists = newData.find(e => e.name === item['Month/Year']);
    if (exists) { // if the date exists in the array already
 if (item.group === 'green') {
            exists.gr = item.flights;
        } else {
         exists.hv = item.flights;
 }
    } else {
        temp.name = item['Month/Year'];
        if (item.group === 'green') {
            temp.gr = item.flights;
        } else {
         temp.hv = item.flights;
 }
        newData.push(temp);
    }
});

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants the data merged by date.

Comment: oh right, thanks @EmileBergeron, my corrected one should be what he wants. Also thanks for adding the snippet.